# Apply different functions to every nth row

Tags: r, nested-loops, lapply

I have a large dataframe:

```
age<- c(25,25,25,25,25,30,30,30,30,30)
pop<-c(1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,800,800,800,800,800)
df<-rbind(age,pop)
```

Actually I have in the same dataframe the iteration of this structure multiple times (for each sex and year).
What I want to do is, to change the ageclasses to increasing numbers- beginning in every 5th. row. To have it like this:

```
age<- c(25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34)
pop<-c(1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,800,800,800,800,800)
df_new<-rbind(age,pop)
```

My thougths were about to apply age +0, age +1, age +2, age +3, age +4; to every multiple of 1st,2nd,3rd,4rd,5rd row.
I tried nested loops or lapply but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data should be structured in this format.

```
age<- c(25,25,25,25,25,30,30,30,30,30)
pop<-c(1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,800,800,800,800,800)
df<-data.frame(age,pop)
```

You can use `seq` function.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(age = seq(min(age), length.out = n()))

#   age  pop
#1   25 1000
#2   26 1000
#3   27 1000
#4   28 1000
#5   29 1000
#6   30  800
#7   31  800
#8   32  800
#9   33  800
#10  34  800
```

If you want to do this for each `sex` and `year` variables you can add them in `group_by` :

```
df %>% group_by(sex, year) %>% mutate(age = seq(min(age), length.out = n()))
```

Comment: I took the last one with group by sex and year and it worked well for the whole dataframe! thanks a lot for the fast answer!

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
t(df) %>% as_tibble() %>% group_by(age) %>% 
               mutate(age = age+0:(n()-1)) %>% ungroup() %>% as.matrix(df) %>% t()
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
age   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32   33    34
pop 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000  800  800  800  800   800
```

Comment: I just made my example data to be a matrix. This was just false. I tried what you suggested and added my sex and year column to the group by function ``` %>% group_by(age, year, sex) %>% 
               mutate(age = age+0:(n()-1))``` This worked as well pretty good. Thanks a lot!